# Extract keyframe info and byte offset from video ffmpeg/ffprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, keyframe, ffprobe

How can I retrieve each keyframe information from the video using ffmpeg/ffprobe.

I have read a lot stackoverflow questions and answers regarding this but the command only returns the keyframe duration.

I have used this command to extract the keyframe duration

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -of csv "/var/www/html/YoutubeTesting/1080p.mp4"
```

**But the info which I need from each keyframe are**

1- Byte offset from video byte size

2- Duration of keyframe

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pkt_duration_time,pkt_pos -of csv "video.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. I have used your command, it is output in this format

frame,0.041000,5847

Can you please tell me that what is 0.041000 in the output? Also is this is keyframe?

Comment: Duration of KF in seconds. Only KFs as marked by the decoder are shown.

Comment: Thank you,

However I found the command which show the full details of only keyframes.

Thank you for your help also!

Comment: You only asked for two fields in your Q, which is what the answer provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keyframe offset byte and also the frame number with the below command.

```
ffprobe -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pos,best_effort_timestamp_time -of csv INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found myself to extract all info regarding the keygrames. It will be useful for someone.

Just add the **-skip_frame nokey** to the command for example

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -skip_frame nokey -show_frames -v quiet video.mp4
```

It will show the info for the keyframes, the info will contain time, duration, offset bytes etc.