# ffmpeg extract single keyframe to image and get timestamp of keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

After searching for frames in a video that match an image, getting the following output

`[Parsed_blackframe_1 @ 0x55a8513722c0] frame:884 pblack:99 pts:452608 t:35.360000 type:B last_keyframe:864`

How to extract an image of a the `last_keyframe` in the case above `864`?

How to get the timestamp of the `last_keyframe` in the case above `864`?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898868) help regarding keyframe info?

Comment: Once you have the frame #, you can use [`select` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) to get the frame of interest. something like `-vf select=eq(n\,1200)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to extract an image of a the last_keyframe in the case above 864?

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf select=eq(pict_type\,I)*gt(n\,864) -update 1 -vsync 0 last.png
```

- `select` filter keeps only the key(I) frames and(*) frames above #864
- `-update 1` discards/overwrites the previous frame, so the final frame is saved
- `-vsync 0` keeps encoder from unnecessarily making copies of the key frames to fill the time

> How to get the timestamp of the last_keyframe in the case above 864?

I don't know if there is a way to do this in FFmpeg, but with FFprobe you can run the following to get all the keyframe timestamps:

```
ffprobe -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -show_entries frame=pts_time
```

References:

- [Extract keyframe info and byte offset from video ffmpeg/ffprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898868)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1448665
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect